# Python Kernel Crash

Tags: python, canopy

I am a school student taking AP computer science and we are learning python currently. Now my problem starts with Enthought Canopy, when I open the code editor up the kernel it states that the kernel needs to be connected

[image]

After I click that I click on use local managed kernel. After 5 seconds of trying to connect it tells gives me that the kernel has crashed and says the following:

```
The ipython kernel (user Python environment) has terminated with error code 1. This may be due to a bug in your code or in the kernel itself.

The output captured from the kernel process is shown below:
```

It says on the Ipython session that it is trying connect to the kernel but nothing happens

```
 Connecting to Kernel: c:\users\diptip~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgmbhng.json
```

I have a win 10 laptop 64bit, and my user name is all ASCII letters. Please if someone can help me resolve this issue. I read an article about this in a previous post but the person apparently got the error because his name was non-ASCII, and my canopy version is 2.1.9

[second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWGB9.png)

Comment: Show details please.

Comment: I added another picture, let me know if you need anything else

Comment: I also updated all the contents in the package manager, but that still didn't work

Comment: Please post text as code formatted text, not screenshots. The first one is fine, but the important part is the output of the kernel startup in the second view. That will literally spell out why the kernel crashed.

Comment: I did what u asked

Comment: I'm going to guess that c:\users\diptip~1\appdata\local\temp\tmpgmbhng.json is some sort of log file. What does it say?

Comment: A big part of a task like this is tracing through all the outputs of a program to diagnose the error. It doesn't become any less frustrating with expertise.

Answer (score 0):

sorry that you're having problems. When the kernel crashes on startup, it's likely because of either blockage from security (AV or firewall) software, or having conflicting environment variables. Try temporarily disabling your security software, then resetting both the configuration and the Python environment from the Canopy Tools => Troubleshoot menu. If that doesn't help, then you can submit a feedback report from the Canopy Help menu, though with holiday schedules I'm not sure how soon we'd reply to it.